# How to get key up event of all select of form in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get key up event of all select of particular form in jquery.

I am successfully achieve this for textbox by doing this

```
$("#formName").on("keyup", ":input", function () {
        //Code here
});
```

while I am trying to do this with select combo box with following

```
$("#formName").on("keyup", ":select", function () {
            //Code here
});
```

It gives me javascript error.

```
Line: 4179
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select
```

Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no selector `:select` specifically for select elements in jQuery like `:input`. The reason `:input` exists is that it combines inputs, textareas, select and and buttons. But you don't need one for selectbox only because you can  use `select` tag name itself. Also `keyup` event makes little sense for selectbox so you probably need `change` event:

```
$("#formName").on("change", "select", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `:`

```
$("#formName").on("keyup", "select", function () {
            //Code here    ^^ here
});
```